# How to run onEdit on multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

My code is a scheduler that makes a user sign-up to a particular slot in a particular sheet. The problem is that the code works only on the first sheet ("Jan 20 Mon").

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Jan 20 Mon");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Jan 21 Tue");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Jan 22 Wed");
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("Jan 23 Thurs");
  var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName("Jan 24 Fri");

  var condition1as1 = sheet1.getRange("B2").getValue(); var condition1bs1 = sheet1.getRange("C2").getValue(); var condition1cs1 = sheet1.getRange("D2").getValue(); var condition1ds1 = sheet1.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var condition1as2 = sheet2.getRange("B2").getValue(); var condition1bs2 = sheet2.getRange("C2").getValue(); var condition1cs2 = sheet2.getRange("D2").getValue(); var condition1ds2 = sheet1.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var condition1as3 = sheet3.getRange("B2").getValue(); var condition1bs3 = sheet3.getRange("C2").getValue(); var condition1cs3 = sheet3.getRange("D2").getValue(); var condition1ds3 = sheet1.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var condition1as4 = sheet4.getRange("B2").getValue(); var condition1bs4 = sheet4.getRange("C2").getValue(); var condition1cs4 = sheet4.getRange("D2").getValue(); var condition1ds4 = sheet1.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var condition1as5 = sheet5.getRange("B2").getValue(); var condition1bs5 = sheet5.getRange("C2").getValue(); var condition1cs5 = sheet5.getRange("D2").getValue(); var condition1ds5 = sheet1.getRange("E2").getValue();

  if (condition1cs1 == "1" && condition1ds1 == "None") {
    var response = Browser.msgBox("PLEASE RECHECK SCHEDULE AND TID.", condition1as1+" , "+condition1bs1+" Are you sure?", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if (response == "yes") {
      sheet1.hideRows(2,1);
      sheet1.getRange('E2').setValue("1");
      //insert msgBox here
    } else {
      Browser.msgBox("Input again.");
    }
  }

  if (condition1cs2 == "1" && condition1ds2 == "None") {
    var response = Browser.msgBox("PLEASE RECHECK SCHEDULE AND TID.", condition1as2+" , "+condition1bs2+" Are you sure?", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if (response == "yes") {
      sheet2.hideRows(2,1);
      sheet2.getRange('E2').setValue("1");
      //insert msgBox here
    } else {
      Browser.msgBox("Input again.");
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I tried to set-up all the sheets I am working with so I could access them anytime. The first if is for the first sheet (and it works). The second if is for the second sheet (and it doesn't work).

Comment: How do I make it run on multiple sheets? What is the format/principle behind running onEdit on multiple sheets?

Comment: What do you mean by "code works only on the first sheet" ? Can you elaborate

Comment: The first "if" is for the first sheet. The second "if" is for the second sheet. The code only works until the first sheet / first "if". The second "if" doesn't work at all. That said, I will be adding 3 more "if's" for the remaining 3 sheets (which of course wouldn't work either using my code).

Comment: Related [How to make onEdit() trigger function apply to multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34802029/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Read *Spreadsheet Edit Events* in [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events). Using the event that's delivered to an `onEdit` function, you can determine where an edit has occurred, and avoid using any explicit methods to retrieve that information.

**Caveat:** This feature is currently broken with the New Sheets that was introduced Dec 2013. There are enough [Scripting Issues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/sheets) that you should avoid using the New Sheets for now.

This is an example of how you could do that.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = event.source;  // you don't use this, but if you did, here's how to get it

  var cell = event.range;  // This is the cell that was edited
  // TODO: Add code that returns immediately if the edit occurred somewhere we don't care about

  var sheet = cell.getSheet();

  var request = sheet.getRange("B2:E2").getValues();
  var conditionas = request[0];
  var conditionbs = request[1];
  var conditioncs = request[2];
  var conditionds = request[3];

  if (conditioncs == "1" && conditionds == "None") {
    var response = Browser.msgBox("PLEASE RECHECK SCHEDULE AND TID.", conditionas+" , "+conditionbs+" Are you sure?", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if (response == "yes") {
      sheet.hideRows(2,1);
      sheet.getRange('E2').setValue("1");
      //insert msgBox here
    } else {
      Browser.msgBox("Input again.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Prototype Code")

Comment: `onEdit(event)` - If you don't declare the parameter, it's `undefined`.