# Google Sheet Global onEdit

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is it possible to use the onEdit function to fire on multiple SpreadSheet, and then just have a switch statement for each individual SpreadSheet?

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit), the `onEdit()` trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. Most `onEdit()` triggers use the information in the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to respond appropriately.

So it is not documented if you can use this `onEdit()` for multiple Spreadsheet, but I found here a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802029/how-to-make-onedit-trigger-function-apply-to-multiple-sheets) that explains how to use or apply `onEdit()` trigger function to multiple sheets.

Check also this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zM_2WzX2K6g) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, What I want to do is instead of for each Spreadsheet a set of code, that my colleagues are able to see when they click on the script editor. Have all the code centralized so that when any of the spreadsheets that I own is edited, the required code gets run.